# Little annoying keyboard issue with edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I'm new to Android/Java ... I created some basic application with basic widget, and i have an issue with EditText, here it is:

I create a normal EditText, nothing special format:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/etEmails"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</EditText>
```

This EditText is on top of the activity's content view, so whenever i open this activity, the EditText is "activated" (ready to get some input) so the keyboard is showed up on the screen, blocking lots of visibility.... Assuming i want to see some information below the EditText before actually edit it, then it's very inconvenient

If you don't get what i mean, the example is Google Translator app, it has a EditText on top of it, and it won't show up the keyboard in the first place, you have touch the EditText to "activate" it (NEWEST VERSION, older version has the same issue as i mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

in your `onCreate()` to make sure the **keyboard only pops up when a user clicks into an EditText**